# ActiveMQ queue messages timestamp

Tags: timestamp, activemq-classic

I'm using ActiveMQ to gather messages that comes from different producers in a queue. I noticed that messages ready to be consumed in the broker's queue have a field named "Timestamp". This is the time in which the message is sent by the producer to the broker or the time in which the broker receives the message? And if the first case is true, suppose the producer P1 sent the message at time t1 which arrives to the broker at time t2, while another producer P2 sent a message at time t3 and the broker receives it at time t4, with t3 > t1 and t2 > t4. In which order these messagges will be queued and so consumed ? So I want to know if the order of the messages in the queue is given by the order in which the broker receives these messages, or by the timestamp of their "send" in the producer.

Apologize if my question is a bit confused,

thank you for helping !!!

I'm sending messagges with these lines:

```java
Destination destination = session.createQueue(jmsQueue);
producer = session.createProducer(destination);
TextMessage toSend = session.createTextMessage("some message");
producer.send(toSend);

/*
I'm not creating a session every time, I just want to show how I send messagges, with this example.
*/
```

This is  a screenshoot of the AcitveMQ's web console, which shows the "Timestamp" property I'm referring to.
[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85EQP.png)

Comment: How exactly are you observing this 'field named "Timestamp"'? Are you looking at it via the web console? If so, could you provide a screenshot? Also, how are you sending the messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the messages in the queue is given by the order in which the broker receives those messages, not by the time they are sent. The timestamp property on the message does not determine the order of the message in the queue in any way.

When messages arrive at the broker they are placed in the queue. The queue is ordered and has first-in-first-out (i.e. FIFO) semantics. The messages may have timestamps or they may not. Some protocols and APIs use timestamps, others don't. Whether or not the message has a timestamp has nothing fundamentally to do with the order of the messages in the queue.

*If* the messages have timestamps those timestamps *may* reflect the order of the messages in the queue. Then again, they might not. The timestamps make no determination about the order of the messages in the queue.

Comment: And what is it that determines the order of consumption, if not the timestamp of arrival?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. Hope that helps!